# How to read and write a tiff image using java

Tags: java, tiff

If anyone knows how to do this, please help :-( 
I want to see a very simple code that works.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ImageIO](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) which supports TIFF.

Comment: Please, when you get a chance, could you show me a sample code that I can refer to?

Answer (score 0):

I just found this in another thread:

[Can't read and write a TIFF image file using Java ImageIO standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954685/cant-read-and-write-a-tiff-image-file-using-java-imageio-standard-library/1958845#1958845)

Looks like it doesn't use the ImageIO library.