# How can I convert HTML to TIFF images?

Tags: java, html, tiff

I am working on a project where I need to convert an HTML file to a TIFF image file format.  I know `Java Imaging API` exists, but from where I can download it for `64-bit JDK`, and are there any tutorials for that?  I read a lots of answers related to this on SO but still I am confused.  I just want a snippet of code to convert HTML or PDF or Excel to TIFF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [WebVector](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/webvector/) for HTML files - it converts a HTML page to PNG. The source is available and it should not be too difficult to change the PNG output to TIFF using the java imaging API: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898311/reading-and-writing-out-tiff-image-in-java) might be an inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

One process that I follow to resolve this is to transform your HTML to [XSL-FO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Formatting_Objects), then use [Apache Fop](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) to transform your output to an image format, such as PDF or TIFF.

The item that you would be missing is mapping HTML to FO, which could be done using XSLT, or via an app like [HTML2FO](http://html2fo.sourceforge.net/).