# How do I read a TIFF image in Java into a BufferedImage?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, tiff, javax.imageio

I was having a problem where my image analysis program would crash whenever I used TIFF images. I found that the problem was that `BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file)` was returning null, even though the file existed. With some extra research, I found that [the ImageIO class doesn't support TIFF images by default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html), but that the Java Advanced Imaging JARS would fix my problem. I was wondering how I could get JAI working under eclipse (for windows) so that I could use my program. I've done some searching, bu there is no clear guide that I can find.

Alternatively, if there is a different class/method for reading images into `BufferedImage` objects, I could use that. I even have the program detecting the file extension so if it works only for TIFF files that's fine.

Comment: You can download TIFF extentions for `ImageIO` [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/current-142188.html) (under the section Java Advanced Imaging-Image I/O Tools Downloads).  You need to place these in the `ext` directory of your JRE and then load away, although it won't support all TIFF variations...(it appears the downloads have moved to [here](https://java.net/projects/imageio) :P)

Comment: PS: You also try [the TIFF plugin](http://haraldk.github.io/TwelveMonkeys/#aldusadobe-tagged-image-file-format-tiff) from my TwelveMonkeys library.

Answer (score 4):

We can use  ImageIO class to read and display TIFF images.. Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898311/reading-and-writing-out-tiff-image-in-java) to see if this helps..Found in one more thread.

Comment: I don't think you should post a link to a different question asking the same thing, instead it's more appropriate to flag as duplicate.