# Resize existing JavaFX image

Tags: javafx

I have to load images:

```
Image image = new Image(f.toURI().toString(), width, height, true, true);
```

Since I also have tiffs, I have to load them differently using JAI:

```
BufferedImage read = ImageIO.read(f);
Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(read, null);
```

Now I have an Image object, but it has the wrong size. Image offers no methods to resize the object. How do I resize is so it has the same size as if I would load a jpg or png with the shown line?

Comment: Maybe you can read the tiff, convert it to for ex. to bmp and open it again as an Image? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2898596/4170073

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like there should be an easier way to do this, but you can try:

```
BufferedImage read = ImageIO.read(f);
int[] pixels = new int[width * height] ;
PixelGrabber grabber = new PixelGrabber(read.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH), 
    0, 0, width, height, 0, pixels, width);
grabber.grabPixels();
WritableImage fxImage = new WritableImage(width, height);
PixelWriter pw = fxImage.getPixelWriter();
pw.setPixels(0, 0, width, height, PixelFormat.getIntArgbInstance(), pixels, 0, width);
```

Now `fxImage` is a `javafx.scene.image.Image` that has dimensions `width` by `height`.

Be aware that `PixelGrabber.grabPixels()` is a blocking call, so you will need to handle `InterruptedException`s. For large images you might want to do this in a `Task` executed on a background thread, so as not to block the FX Application Thread.