# my java app opens certain image files,but cant figure out how to open .tiff

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application, tiff

I'm a beginner and I find it hard to figure out how to make my program working with .tiff files.I'd be grateful if there is someone there to tell me where exactly and what to write in addition to my code -> here is the tutorial I've watched for my app -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hF8h9rhotME ... Please,help :P Thank you a lot

Comment: Check the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898311/reading-and-writing-out-tiff-image-in-java

Comment: I saw it mate but i couldn't figure it out where exactly to write this :D

Comment: TIFF support for the `ImageIO` is supplied via the [JAI API](https://github.com/jai-imageio/jai-imageio-core), you need to install this in your `ext` directory of your JRE.  Take a closer look at [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

Comment: As JAI is unsupported/no longer maintained, I'll just mention that my [TwelveMonkeys ImageIO project supports TIFF](http://haraldk.github.io/TwelveMonkeys/#aldusadobe-tagged-image-file-format-tiff). In most cases it can be used as a direct replacement for the JAI ImageIO TIFF plugin.