# Tiff image in java applet

Tags: java, applet, tiff, jai

I am trying simple java applet program to display tiff image  as below

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;


/* <applet code="Form1" width=100 height=50>
</applet> */  
public class Form1 extends Applet
{
     ImageIcon image ;

       public void init(){

           image = new ImageIcon("C:/Documents and Settings/inos002827/Desktop/a.tif");
       }

        public void paint(Graphics g){

              g.drawImage(image.getImage(), 0,0,this);

        }


}
```

But I am getting blank applet.Same is working for jpeg image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For TIFF Support, see [Java Advanced Imaging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/jai-142803.html).

From the [FAQ](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jaifaq.html#fileformat)

> #### What image file formats are supported?
>
> The codec classes supplied with Java Advanced Imaging 1.1.2_01 support BMP, GIF (read only), FlashPix (read only), JPEG, PNG, PNM, **TIFF,** and WBMP.

Answer (score 0):

From memory, Tiff files are not supported via this means.  You will need to look towards the ImageIO API and probably a third party library.

Oddly enough, a 3 second search of google found this [Can't read and write a TIFF image file using Java ImageIO standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954685/cant-read-and-write-a-tiff-image-file-using-java-imageio-standard-library)