# How to convert inputstream of grayscale image to binary?

Tags: java, image, tiff, grayscale

I am reading an grayscale tiff image into inputstream using

```
                InputStream is=objCMBObject.getDataStream();
                bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
                response.setContentType(mimeType);
                OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
```

and writing this stream into applet .but now I want to convert this grayscale image to binary image before writing to the applet. I don't want to save the image in file.
How to convert inputstream of grayscale to binary?

I can convert the image into binary if I have x,y coordinates but I don't know how to get it from inputstream.
Please guide.

Comment: What do you mean 'binary'? You already have it in binary.

Comment: @EJP I meant just black and white.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to manipulate an image, [`javax.imageio.ImageIO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) can be of great use. You can use that to load the image from the stream, apply some operation like a [`ColorConvertOp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/image/ColorConvertOp.html), and write the result back to a stream.

As `ImageIO` doesn't neccessarily support TIFF out of the box, you might have to use a suitable library to provide TIFF support. Answers to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1954685/1468366) suggest using [Java Advanced Imaging](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/iio.html) for this.