# How to use jai-imageio in IntelliJ plugin

Tags: java, image-processing, intellij-idea, tesseract, jai

I'm developing a plugin for intelliJ.

This requires to use tesseract. When i tied to execute it as an console application, it works fine.

But when i tried executing a plugin i get the following exception,

```
SEVERE: Need to install JAI Image I/O package.
https://java.net/projects/jai-imageio/
java.lang.RuntimeException: Need to install JAI Image I/O package.
https://java.net/projects/jai-imageio/
    at net.sourceforge.vietocr.ImageIOHelper.getImageByteBuffer(ImageIOHelper.java:254)
```

in the following statement

```
 final TIFFImageWriteParam tiffWriteParam = new TIFFImageWriteParam(Locale.US);

        tiffWriteParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_DISABLED);

        // Get tif writer and set output to file
        final Iterator<ImageWriter> writers =  ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName(TIFF_FORMAT);

        if (!writers.hasNext()) {
            throw new RuntimeException(JAI_IMAGE_WRITER_MESSAGE);
        }
```

`ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName` returns null

I'm able execute this as a console application, but when i try to execute as a plugin for intelliJ it fails.

Can anyone please guide how to use jai-image io in IntelliJ plugin.

Regards,
Siva N B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to add  jai_codec.jar, jai_core.jar and jai_imageio.jar to jre's ext folder.

When creating as a plugin, the classpath is different as of the console.

I followed the following link,
https://www.java.net/node/683477

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have different classpathes for Intellij and your console. The Intellij version is not able to read tiff files as the java-imageio is missing. You could look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954685/cant-read-and-write-a-tiff-image-file-using-java-imageio-standard-library) to find the jar, or maybe it is easier to look which jars are on your console classpath which are missing for intellij.

Edit: Some more details. The java imageio lib needs a plugin to read tiff and bmp files. The plugin is usually not bundled with the lib. And it is usually a pain to find the correct jar.