# Read Tiff format in Java eclipse

Tags: java, tiff

How do i read a TIFF image using Java IMAGEIO library??(I am using Eclipse Luna)..And once i download the plugin(JAR files) how to give the Classpath so that it can read my input TIFF image file?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Okay.I wil post the code snippet.

Comment: TIFF is not supported by default by ImageIO. See [Can't read and write a TIFF image file using Java ImageIO standard library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954685/cant-read-and-write-a-tiff-image-file-using-java-imageio-standard-library). And search the web for "java imageio tiff".

Comment: I searched the same.I got jai_imageio-1.1.jar.zip Now i dont know how to use that..

Comment: at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReader.read(TIFFImageReader.java:1154)
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1448)
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1308)
 at Median3x3.<init>(Median3x3.java:43)
 at Median3x3.main(Median3x3.java:108) .....Getting this error

Comment: Please *update your question* with the code you have and and the *full* stack trace you get. Possibly also attach or link the TIFF file you used. If we can't reproduce your problem, it's hard for us to help. :-)

Comment: Hey I got it.Actually the size of the image was causing the above error.It was too huge.

Answer (score 4):

Here a quick example to convert a TIFF image into a PNG image.

```
// quick conversion example
File inputFile = new File("image.tiff");
File outputFile = new File("output.png");
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(inputFile);
ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputFile);
```

Print a list of all supported formats of the JAI ImageIO library.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
...
for (String format : ImageIO.getWriterFormatNames()) {
    System.out.println("format = " + format);
}
```

**note** For the convertion of image formats which have no built-in support a supporting library must be in the classpath. To find the supported formats check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html or the snippet above.

e.g. for TIFF you could use the [jai_imageio-1.1.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.media/jai_imageio/1.1) (or [newer](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.jai-imageio/jai-imageio-core)).

```
javac -cp jai_imageio-1.1.jar:. Main.java
java -cp jai_imageio-1.1.jar:. Main
```

If no TIFF format supporting library is in the classpath the above convertion snippet fails with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!`.

Following formats have built-in support (Java 8)

```
BMP
GIF
JPEG
PNG
WBMP
```

`jai_imageio-1.1.jar` adds support for

```
JPEG2000
PNM
RAW
TIFF
```

**edit** As times goes by and Java 9 is released, a small update, because Java 9 supports TIFF now out of the box.

compile and run with Java 9 without an additional library

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
class TiffToPng {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File inputFile = new File("image.tiff");
        File outputFile = new File("output.png");
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(inputFile);
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputFile);
    }
}
```

to find supported [ImageReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageReader.html) / [ImageWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriter.html) formats resp. MIME types you could use following snippets

```
for (String format : ImageIO.getReaderFormatNames()) {
    System.out.println("format = " + format);
}
...
for (String format : ImageIO.getReaderMIMETypes()) {
    System.out.println("format = " + format);
}


for (String format : ImageIO.getWriterFormatNames()) {
    System.out.println("format = " + format);
}
...
for (String format : ImageIO.getWriterMIMETypes()) {
    System.out.println("format = " + format);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.But i dont want to convert it to PNG format.I wanna keep TIFF format itself for I/O operations

Comment: @Codebeginner it was only a simple example. If you want to work with the TIFF image itself, then you should operate on the `BufferedImage`. Have a look on the [Oracle Java 2D tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/) for further informations.

Comment: Does the ImageIO come from javax?

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
```

Just put the below jar :-

- If you are using eclipse, just add it to referenced libraries.
- If you are using just simple java file and running it through console, just paste this jar in the class path.

> jai_imageio-1.1.jar |
>   http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/jai/jai_imageio-1.1.jar.zip

And Import the following :

```
import com.sun.media.imageio.plugins.tiff.*;
```