# How do I read TIFF files in Java 10?

Tags: tiff, java-10

I tried just doing:

```
File inputFile = new File("image.tif");
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(inputFile);
```

because I thought Java 10 didn't need extra libraries to handle tiff files but the BufferedImage is null.

Comment: Can you cite any sources for TIFF support in Java 10?

Comment: I saw in lots of posts that said that Java 9 supported it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29096913/read-tiff-format-in-java-eclipse near bottom), so I just assumed that Java 10 would.

Comment: The above code should work with no extra imports using Java 9 and later, thanks to [JEP 262: TIFF Image I/O](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/262). However, TIFF is an extremely flexible format, and not all variations of TIFF is supported by the standard TIFF plugin. If you attach or link a TIFF that causes this problem, I can probably give you a more detailed explanation.

Comment: First, test the availability of a TIFF reader using `ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("tiff").forEachRemaining(System.out::println);` Since the image provider doesn’t consider the file name, but the actual content, it is perfectly possible to silently get `null` for invalid files, when they are not recognized as TIFF. Request a TIFF reader explicitly to get an error feedback: `ImageReader ir = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("tiff").next(); 
 ir.setInput(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new File("image.tif"))); 
 BufferedImage bi = ir.read(0);`

Answer (score -1):

Since JDK 9 this should be possible:

```
private Image readTiffImage() throws IOException
{

final InputStream tiffImage = TiffExample.class.getResourceAsStream("image.tiff");

final BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(tiffImage);
final Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);
return image;
}
```

Comment: I get an IllegalArgumentException: image == null