# Merging multiple JPGs from stdin into multi-file TIFF

Tags: java, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I currently have the following command line with ImageMagick:

```
convert jpg:- -density 200x200 -monochrome -colors 2 -compress Group4 tif:-
```

I would like to be able to pipe *more* than one JPG image in stdin, and have those merged into a [multi-file TIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format#Multiple_subfiles)

More precisely, I am doing this from Java via `ProcessBuilder`, so I am not able to (easily or safely) do things like `convert jpg:fd1 ...`.

I have tried merging all the JPG files into a single `byte[]` in Java and writing that to the sub-processes stdin, but the result was that ImageMagick only processed the first JPG.

Is what I want to do possible?

Comment: If you are looking for Java solution refer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954685/cant-read-and-write-a-tiff-image-file-using-java-imageio-standard-library/62132533#62132533

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why that doesn't work as you have it, but for the moment, while I am thinking about it, the following does work and may be of use:

```
for f in *.jpg; do convert "$f" miff:- ; done | convert miff:- result.tif
```

Comment: I will poke it with a stick again. Though, thinking about it, it might be worth converting each image to a MIFF first, then piping all of those through to IM. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I guess there's a reason why `MIFF` is ImageMagick's streaming file format... ;-)

Comment: Converting them all to `MIFF`, then merging them into a single `byte[]`, then sending that through works as expected. Just tried again with JPGs and it does not work.