# Trying to read image blob from oracle DB with ImageIO.read in Java not working

Tags: java, oracle, image, blob, javax.imageio

I have some images stored in an oracle DB as blobs. I want to read them and display in a JLabel. After reading them, I have tried using ImageIO.read but it always returns null. See my code below:

```
Blob blob = rs.getBlob(2);
BufferedImage frontImg = ImageIO.read(blob.getBinaryStream());
lblFrontImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(frontImg));
```

I am able to save the image to a file however using the following code so I know the image is valid:

```
Blob blob = rs.getBlob(2);
InputStream in = blob.getBinaryStream();
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("test.jpg");
byte[] buff = new byte[4096];  
int len = 0;
while ((len = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
   out.write(buff, 0, len);
}
out.close();
```

Other ways I have tried to display the image in a JLabel

```
byte[] frontBytes = rs.getBytes(2);
BufferedImage frontImg = ImageIO.read(new 
ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent));
lblFrontImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(frontImg));
```

And

```
byte[] frontBytes = rs.getBytes(2);
BufferedImage image;
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(frontBytes);
image = ImageIO.read(bis);
bis.close();
lblFrontImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
```

Also

```
InputStream in = blob.getBinaryStream();
image = ImageIO.read(in);
byte[] frontImgBytes = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
System.out.println("front bytes length: ====\n" + frontImgBytes.length);
BufferedImage frontImage = ImageIO.read(new 
ByteArrayInputStream(frontImgBytes));
lblFrontImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(frontImage));
```

Tried a lot of ways, just keep getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`. No other exception or error. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe your first attempt should have worked fine, if the image is in a format ImageIO understands. Can you please attach or link the image file you stored to disk, without using ImageIO? That would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I finally realised it was because the images were TIFF images. I couldn't use the default ImageIO libraries. I noticed another StackOverflow thread here [Can't read and write a TIFF image file using Java ImageIO standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954685/cant-read-and-write-a-tiff-image-file-using-java-imageio-standard-library) and used your twelvemonkeys libraries  @haraldK and it worked fine. Thanks a lot.