# How to convert PNG<->JPEG<->TIFF images

Tags: java, java-io

is there any way I can convert PNG<->JPEG<->TIFF images in Java?
I have String i/p passing parameter (PNG or JPEG converted to []byte which get converted to String) to ConvertImage(String xyz) method.

String ConvertImage(String xyz)

So I am looking for following conversion from single method and return byte array or string and then finally I want to store in DB.

1.if i/p is PNG converted o/p is JPEG

2.if i/p is JPEG converted  o/p is PNG

3.If i/p is PNG or JPEG converted  o/p is TIFF

I am using JAI right now for this conversion(In my prev post I did not mention all these details sorry about that) but don't want to use JAI now.

Please let me know if you have any quick solution for all these 3 types?

Thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: In addition, you want to read [Can't read and write a TIFF image file using Java ImageIO standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954685/cant-read-and-write-a-tiff-image-file-using-java-imageio-standard-library?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and [Working with Images](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html)

Answer (score 5):

Most image types can be read into memory using a simple call to `ImageIO.read`:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;

public class ImageTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("image.png"));//Or image.jpg or image.tiff, etc.
    }
}
```

Writing images can then be done by passing a `RenderedImage` (which `BufferedImage` is an implementation of) to `ImageIO.write`:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;

public class ImageTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("image.png"));//Or image.jpg or image.tiff, etc.
        String[] formatNames = ImageIO.getWriterFormatNames();
        //A robust use would validate whatever format you're intending to use against 
        //the canonical list of format names retrieved by that call
        ImageIO.write(image, "tiff", new File("image.tiff"));
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: Tiff isn’t supported out of the box (at least while I was using it in Java 7) - You’ll need to install the Java Advance Imaging API to get it - unless, as I read, you’re using Java 9+

Comment: Sorry, couldn't post links from the mobile App - From [Writing/Saving an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html), [Java 8 JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) and [Can't read and write a TIFF image file using Java ImageIO standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954685/cant-read-and-write-a-tiff-image-file-using-java-imageio-standard-library?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Comment: And also the [Java 9 JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) which does list it

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable help. I am just trying for TIFF and yes seems like java io is not supporting. but I don't want to use JAI. what should I use for TIFF? If i get any sample example then it will be great.